# Dropping the interaction term when the interaction effect is not significant?

Tags: interaction

Can I drop the interaction term from the model if the interaction  term is insignificant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose of your analysis is to say something about the interaction term, then it is more convincing to keep the interaction in and show that it is not significant.

Comment: And by keeping it you will preserve type I error and unbiasedness of the estimate of residual variance.